# Уникальное имя переменных в цикле c#

Tags: c#

Я создаю лист направлений `List<Direction> directions = new List<Direction>();`, который содержит в себе объекты класса `Direction`, затем я в этот этот лист добавляю направление `AddDirection(directions);`, например "Владивосток-Москва" . Потом я создаю поезд `List<Carriage> train1 = new List<Carriage>();`, состоящий из объектов класса `Carriage`.

Соответственно, при создании нового направления `AddDirection(directions);` мне нужно создать новый поезд, но в данном коде я могу добавлять поезд только вручную, создавая новый лист. Но я хочу чтобы названия создавались сами, т.е. скорее всего это будет какой-то цикл, который создаёт новый лист, но уже с другим названием, например не `train1`, а `train2`, где `2` должна добавляться сама. Можно создать counter и при создании направления делать инкремент. Но как добавлять `итератор i` к строке не знаю. Как такое можно реализовать?
Есть задумка,можно создать ещё один лист, который содержит в себе листы `train`, но как-то слишком громоздко уже получается

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        List<Direction> directions = new List<Direction>();

        Console.WriteLine("Добавить новое направление");
        AddDirection(directions);                    //создаём направление
        List<Carriage> train1 = new List<Carriage>(); //создаём поезд
        AddCarriage(train, rand);                    //создаём несколько вагонов для поезда
        AddCarriage(train, rand); 
        AddCarriage(train, rand); 

    }

    static void AddCarriage(List<Carriage> train, Random rand)
    {
        train.Add(new Carriage(rand));
    }
    static void AddDirection(List<Direction> directions)
    {
        directions.Add(new Direction(Console.ReadLine()));
    }
}

class Direction
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Direction(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
class Carriage
{
    public int Capacity { get; private set; }

    public Carriage(Random rand)
    {
        Capacity = rand.Next(30, 50);
    }
}
```

Comment: Правильно сделать `public Direction Direction { get; private set; }` в классе `Carriage`, вы о таком варианте не думали?

Comment: ```for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) new Direction("train" + i.ToString());``` создаст 100 направлений, или что вы имели ввиду?

Comment: _Но как добавлять итератор i к строке не знаю._ - никак, используй еще один лист в котором и будешь хранить создаваемые переменные

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы хотите создавать список поездов динамически, то вам нужен все тот же `List`. Но из-за того, что у вас поезд - это список вагонов, то у вас получится такая вот каша:

```
List<Carriage> train1 = new List<Carriage>();
List<List<Carriage>> trainList = new List<List<Carriage>>();
trainList.Add(train1);
```

Предлагаю вам сделать отдельный класс `Train` для поездов, тогда такой вложенности можно избежать. Ожидаемое вами поведение может быть реализовано примерно так (при добавлении направления создаем поезд с тремя вагонами):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        List<Direction> directions = new List<Direction>();
        var trains = new List<Train>();

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Добавить новое направление");

            var direction = new Direction(Console.ReadLine());
            var train = new Train(direction);
            train.AddCarriage(new Carriage(rand));
            train.AddCarriage(new Carriage(rand));
            train.AddCarriage(new Carriage(rand));

            trains.Add(train);
            directions.Add(direction);
            
            Console.WriteLine("Нажмите 'q' для завершения или любую другую клавишу, чтобы продолжить");
        } while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Q);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Direction
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Direction(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
class Carriage
{
    public int Capacity { get; private set; }

    public Carriage(Random rand)
    {
        Capacity = rand.Next(30, 50);
    }
}

class Train
{
    private readonly List<Carriage> _carriages;

    public Direction Direction { get; }
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Carriage> Carriages
    {
        get { return _carriages; }
    }

    public Train(Direction direction)
    {
        Direction = direction;
        _carriages = new List<Carriage>();
    }

    public void AddCarriage(Carriage carriage)
    {
        _carriages.Add(carriage);
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое, очень трудно для меня дается ооп, буду сравнивать ваш код и мой, спасибо

Comment: Ваше решение в корне помогло мне разобраться как такое делать, были проблемы с "лист в листе", не понимал как сделать, сейчас под себя адаптировал, все работает, Спасибо

Comment: @Rotmayer рад помочь! Если мой ответ вам действительно помог, можете поставить "галочку" слева от вопроса

Comment: @Rotmayer а точнее слева от ответа